# How to optimize data preprocessing using pandas assign method

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Using Pandas 1.1.4

From amazing [talk by Matt harrison](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zgbUk90aQ6A&t=3492s) I've learned to preprocess dataframe by chaining methods which seems very easy to read for me.

While trying to use chaining I've came across some lines that seems redundant.

Here is MRE:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"st_date":[20210915, 20210914, 20211014, 20211010, 20211014],
                   "language":["python", "python", "python", "java", "java"],
                   "income":[10000, 12000, 11000, 9000, 8000],
                   "next_raise":[2000,4000,3000,2000,1000],
                   "A":[1,2,3,4,5],
                   "B":[3,4,6,7,1]})
def is_weekday(x):
    """1 = weekday"""
    if x <= 4:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

Usually I would preprocess by following:

```
df["st_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["st_date"], format='%Y%m%d') 
df["dayofweek"] = df["st_date"].dt.dayofweek.astype("int8")
df["weekday"] = df["st_date"].dt.dayofweek.apply(is_weekday).astype(np.int8)

df["raise(%)"] = df["next_raise"] / df["income"] * 100
mean_raise = df["raise(%)"].mean()
df["raise_above_mean"] = np.where(df["raise(%)"] > mean_raise, 1, 0) 

df.drop(columns=["A", "B"], inplace=True)
df[["income", "next_raise"]] = df[["income", "next_raise"]].astype("int16")
```

Chaining above methods becomes:

```
def preprocess(df):
    return (df.assign(dayofweek = df["st_date"].dt.dayofweek.astype("int8"),
                      weekday = df["st_date"].dt.dayofweek.apply(is_weekday).astype(np.int8),
                      raise_p = df["next_raise"] / df["income"] * 100,
                      raise_above_mean = np.where((df["next_raise"] / df["income"] * 100) > #2
                                                  (df["next_raise"] / df["income"] * 100).mean(), 1, 0)
                      )
              .astype({"income":"int16", 
                       "next_raise":"int16"})
              .drop(columns=["A", "B"])
             )

df["st_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["st_date"], format='%Y%m%d') #1
new_df = preprocess(df)
```

Here are lines that seem redundant to me so hoping to make it more efficient.

#1 I want to convert "st_date" to datetime inside chain, when I try it it seems like it is not applied before `.dt.dayofweek` is used therefore outputting `AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values`

#2I am calculating "raise percentage(raise_p)" twice(3 including one above), how can I avoid this?

Lastly it would be great to know what you guys prefer(including reasons why): chaining or method above. Also if you know source that explains preprocessing using chaining in more depth, let me know!

Comment: Why do you want to make a perfectly legible set of operations illegible?

Comment: to me, chaining seems more legible.

Comment: You can use assignment expressions to avoid redundancy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert values to datetimes in `assign`, but then need `lambda` function for processing with converted column. Also for `weekday` is custom function not necessary, compare by [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html) for less or equal. Last for `raise_above_mean` is also necessary `lamba` function, because processing counted column:

```
def preprocess(df):
    return (df.assign(st_date = pd.to_datetime(df["st_date"], format='%Y%m%d'),
                      dayofweek = lambda x: x["st_date"].dt.dayofweek.astype("int8"),
                      weekday = lambda x: x["st_date"].dt.dayofweek.le(4).astype(np.int8),
                      raise_p = df["next_raise"] / df["income"] * 100,
                      raise_above_mean = lambda x: np.where(x["raise_p"] > x["raise_p"].mean(), 1, 0)
                      )
              .astype({"income":"int16", 
                       "next_raise":"int16"})
              .drop(columns=["A", "B"])
             )
```

Comment: do you prefer chaining?

Comment: @haneulkim - it depends, obviously not, because it is slowier.

Comment: @haneulkim - also if use counted columns like here, it is more typing, because need `lambda` functions.